# return data from table storage to PowerApps

Tags: azure-table-storage, powerapps

I would like to work with table storage withing PowerApps. I understand that the built-in connector doesn't work (not authorized error message), I did some research on this. So I failed over to Flow.

So, I query a table and would like to list all the entities. Calling the flow with a button, data is returned.
Now, with the `Respond to PowerApps` action I couldn't return the whole collection, only distinct values. (or, can I somehow parse the json as string with PA?)

Next option is the http response action, as described [here](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/return-an-array-from-flow-to-powerapps-response-method/).
Unfortunately I cannot make it work. The JSON that is returned is valid and matches against the schema:

```
{
  "odata.metadata": "https://mystorageaccount.table.core.windows.net/$metadata#busz&$select=rowkey,%20letszam,%20rendszam",
  "value": [
    {
      "odata.etag": "W/\"datetime'2019-03-13T19%3A05%3A26.0156798Z'\"",
      "letszam": 40,
      "rendszam": "abc-123",
      "rowkey": null
    },
    {
      "odata.etag": "W/\"datetime'2019-03-13T19%3A06%3A03.537472Z'\"",
      "letszam": 50,
      "rendszam": "def-234",
      "rowkey": null
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I try to display the data in PowerApps, all I see is "true".

```
ClearCollect(buszok;'GetData'.Run("busz"))
```

The `buszok` collection only contains on record and its `value` column is `true`.

Looking for advise how to go further. Either with Flow or native PowerApps. The goal is to read/write table storage.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in **Premium** connector for [Azure Table Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuretables/) (not sure if this is the one you mean) that does the job.

However, you may need to add the Power App IP Address (*100.64.0.0/10*) to the whitelist on the Firewalls and virtual networks tab of the Storage Account to get it working.

Comment: Just to be clear, there is more than one [PowerApps IP address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/limits-and-config#ip-addresses) to whitelist (unless you choose "Allow Azure Services" in the Azure Portal.